# Multiplicar matrices Python

Tags: python, matrices, bucle-for

quisiera entender **el flujo** de estos bucles *for* a cada vuelta, ya que según lo que he entendido de multiplicación de matrices y según el bucle: en la primera vuelta

> i,j y k

tendrían un valor de cero, por lo tanto en

> result[ i ][ j ] es decir: result[0][0]

se almacenaría el resultado de la multiplicación de X[i][k]* Y[k][j], es decir , 12*5 = 60. y al imprimir da 144 según el output que he puesto abajo. y así sucesivamente con todos y no entiendo por qué.

un saludo!

```html
# Program to multiply two matrices using nested loops

# 3x3 matrix
X = [[12,7,3],
    [4 ,5,6],
    [7 ,8,9]]
# 3x4 matrix
Y = [[5,8,1,2],
    [6,7,3,0],
    [4,5,9,1]]
# result is 3x4
result = [[0,0,0,0],
         [0,0,0,0],
         [0,0,0,0]]

# iterate through rows of X
for i in range(len(X)):
   # iterate through columns of Y
   for j in range(len(Y[0])):
       # iterate through rows of Y
       for k in range(len(Y)):
           result[i][j] += X[i][k] * Y[k][j]

for r in result:
   print(r)

#output:
[114, 160, 60, 27]
[74, 97, 73, 14]
[119, 157, 112, 23]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La expresión dentro del bucle más interno es:

```
result[i][j] += X[i][k] * Y[k][j]
```

Si te das cuenta, no hay un `=`, sino un `+=`, es decir, no se guarda el resultado de la multiplicación en `result[0][0]`, sino que *se suma* a lo que hubiera allí.

Dirás, vale, pero allí había cero por lo que al final es lo mismo y deberia sumar 0+60 dando como resultado 60.

Eso es correcto, pero eso es sólo en la primera iteración del bucle en que `k` vale 0. Si te fijas esa expresión está dentro de otro bucle en que va variando `k`. Ya que cada vez que `k` varía *se añade* el resultado a lo que había en `result[0][0]`, el resultado final en ese elemento, tras haber iterado todas las veces sobre el valor de `k`, sería equivalente a:

```
result[0][0] = X[0][0]*Y[0][0] + X[0][1]*Y[1][0] + X[0][2]*Y[2][0]
```

Por tanto el resultado sería:

```
result[0][0] = 12*5 + 7*6 + 3*4
```

Que es 114.

Esa es la forma en que se multiplican matrices. Mientras en la matriz X vas recorriendo los elementos de una fila, en la matriz Y vas recorriendo los de una columna. Se van multiplicando entre sí y sumando todos, y el resultado se asigna al elemento de la matriz resultante que estaría en la intersección entre esa fila y esa columna. Los otros dos bucles exteriores (en `i` y `j`) son para ir variando la fila y columna sobre la que se opera.

En esta imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La matriz inferior representa el resultado. Para calcular el valor del elemento coloreado de violeta, hay que multiplicar cada elemento azul de la primera matriz por cada elemento rojo de la segunda, y sumar todos esos productos. Con eso se habrá calculado sólo el valor de un elemento del resultado. Variando `i` y `j` vas recorriendo todas las posiciones en la matriz resultado, y para cada una, multiplicas la fila `i` de X por la columna `j` de Y.

Answer (score 3):

Miralo de esta forma, en la multiplicación de matrices se realiza **fila x columna**.

La primera iteración, como dijiste, tus variables de control, tienen valor de `cero`, por lo tanto quedaría como lo siguiente:

La primera fila de `x = [12,7,3]`

La primera columna de `y = [5,6,4]`

`[12,7,3] × [5,6,4] = 12×5+7×6+3×4 = 114`

Y así sucesivamente con las demás filas y columnas.

Te dejo un screenshot, del procedimiento:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]